# Why is Cassandra reverting back to the default password?

Tags: docker-compose, cassandra

I have the following docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  cassandra:
    container_name: cassandra
    image: bitnami/cassandra:4.1
#    volumes:
#      - ./bitnami:/bitnami
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_AUTHENTICATOR=PasswordAuthenticator
      - CASSANDRA_AUTHORIZER=CassandraAuthorizer
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=${CASSANDRA_PASSWORD:-cbusha1}
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
      - CASSANDRA_HOSTNAME=${CASSANDRA_HOSTNAME}
```

It works fine but I would like to persist the volume so I uncomment

```
    volumes:
      - ./bitnami:/bitnami
```

but now it won't take the password, it reverts to the `cassandra` password.

How do I change the password when using Cassandra with a local volume?

Comment: Do you have any information in the ./bitmani directory? What happens if you delete it before starting the container?